How to offset points randomly along a curve?
I’m wondering how we can randomly offset points we scattered along a curve
(for example after a curve to point node)

I want to create a slider that randomly offsets my scattered points following the curve (moving them backward or forward along the curve).
I also want the tangent/normal/radius attribute of the points, to still be accurate to the curve even after the offset… (because the points will be moved, their attributes won't be correct with regards to the curve)

So if I understand you correctly, you only want the points to move forward and backward along the curve - not offset from the curve? And the tangents they should carry should be the ones of their new positions or their original positions before moving?

Hello @GordonBrinkmann yes that it is!

My last question was a "this" or "that" question... so which one is it, original or new tangents? The other thing I'm not really sure about is, do you want to place the points on the curve evenly distanced and have a slider to randomize their positions along the curve or do you want them to have random positions on the curve initially and then move them around with a slider?

Yes @GordonBrinkmann the points should move following the curve line a train following a track, but at a randomly distance, forward or backward :)

...so, to ultimately get an answer to this question now asked for the third time: you just need the tangent at the current position, not of the original position?

Not expert in gn, but if you offset along the captured tangent and the curve is not straight, you get your final position outside of the curve space. This approach set the number of points and then divides the spline length by the point number. Then adding or subtracting the random value from this fraction and using the accumulate field to stack these random shifts.Sample curve node is used to get the position along the curve of this accumulated field.


Gordon's approach, same result:



The question does not say offset along the tangent, it says following the curve and keeping the tangent. I guess it means although the new random position has a different tangent, the point should output the tangent of its original position. But I'm not sure about that, that's why I asked for clarification in the comments...

Hey Filanek! Thanks that's correct, but does this technique also refresh the attributes of the points? (tangent/normal?) :)

See my updated answer, I used the Gordon's approach, it is more elegant. You should get all attributes from the sample curve node.

The Spline Parameter > Factor always goes from 0 to 1 on a curve from start to finish. So to place a point along a curve, you can use a Set Position node and read the position at a certain factor by using a Sample Curve node and getting the Position output on whatever Factor value you enter, the same goes for the tangent at this factor.
Now to place a number of points randomly along the curve, you just have to get a Random Value between 0 and 1 to plug into the Factor input of the Sample Curve node. The Position and Tangent vectors will then be the ones on this random factor.
And when you have multiple points for example from a Resample Curve node, each point gets his own random value and so you can sample for each of them a random position along the curve somewhere between start and finish.
Since resampling with a low number of points can change the curvature I would recommend you sample the original smooth curve and then resample the curve with a desired Count to get the number of points you want. But you need a Capture Attribute point to assign the values to the resampled points.
With the Random Value as Factor, the points are now randomly distributed along the curve. To move them altogether along the curve now would just be increasing the factor to move them forward or decreasing the factor to move them backwards. To achieve that, you can plug the Random Value into a Math node set to Add to move the points.
The higher the value that you add, the more points will reach a factor of equal or greater 1, but since the curve stops at 1, all points would clump together at the endpoint. Or if you go in the negative direction, once all points have a factor of 0 or below, they are clumped together at the starting point.
So to have them disappear from the curve, you can use to Compare nodes, one to check if the factor is greater than 1, the other if it is less than 0. The result you combine in a Boolean Math node set to Or and use is as Selection in a Delete Geometry node which you place after the Set Position node. This way all points that move outside of the curve range will disappear.

The result might look something like this, 8 cubes placed randomly on a curve:

And when I now animate the Add value from -1 to 1 I get the following animation:



Hi Gordon, thank you so much for your response! It seems that your answer resolve the question of "offsetting (uniformly) randomly distributed points on a curve", or the question here was to randomly offset distributed points along the curve. The random adjective is related to the offsetting action :-)

@Hellobender The movement should be random? Your comment referring to a train on a track did not really make that clear... since the wagons do not move individually at different speeds and directions  But if that's what you want, instead of adding a single value which gets multiplied, just plug a Random Value with negative Min and positive Max value into the Add node. And if you want the start positions to be evenly distributed, replace the 0 to 1 random values with a Spline Parameter > Factor. (Cannot edit my answer at the moment with screenshots etc., might do it later.)

Oh, I just saw you accepted the other answer. Well then, nevermind you get the idea from my last comment.
